# Blank login screen

Tags: login

When I boot into Linux, then I should get a login screen where I enter my password. But I actually a black and a blank screen, literally. Because I know this is the screen where we enter the password I just start typing and press enter and everything works fine after that. (Recently I've been trying to install CUDA 10.0, with 0 success!)

Comment: Do you see login prompt when you run `login` command after you have already logged-in? Second thing, do you have some fancy stuff (like special characters) inside `/etc/issue`? Try removing this file completely.

Comment: Yes I see login prompt, when I type sudo login. Also, how to access /etc/issue? Is it a command?

Comment: `/etc/issue` is a text file, print it with `cat -A /etc/issue`; a message which you see at the beginning of the login prompt is stored there. It can contain control characters for example to change font colors and do other fancy things with terminal/console.

Comment: This is what I get,         Linux Mint 19 Tara \n \l